# Adicionar dados em array de Sessão

Tags: php, array, session

Estou utilizando PHP para desenvolver uma aplicação e estou utilizando o seguinte código para manter informações em uma sessão e retornar os dados para gerar um alerta para o usuário:

```
class Data{
    const DATA = "DATA";

    public static function setData($type, $data){
        $_SESSION[Data::DATA] = array($type=>$data);
    }

    public static function getData(){
        $data = (isset($_SESSION[Data::DATA]) && $_SESSION[Data::DATA]) ? $_SESSION[Data::DATA] : '';
        Data::clearData();
        return $data;
    }

    public static function clearData(){
        $_SESSION[Data::DATA] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Em uma das minhas rotas, então, eu jogo as informações de que preciso na sessão utilizando o seguinte código:

```
Data::setData(['01' => 'aviso 01', '02' => 'aviso 02']);
```

Só que, nesta mesma rota e em um outro momento, eu estou precisando chamar o setData novamente e colocar mais informações na sessão:

```
Data::setData(['03' => 'aviso 03', '04' => 'aviso 04']);
```

O problema é que, quando eu chamo o método novamente, as primeiras informações são perdidas, sendo mantidas apenas as últimas informações que foram enviadas para a sessão.

Eu gostaria de saber o que preciso fazer para manter todos os dados na sessão, como adicionar novos elementos no array da sessão e como chamar estas informações.

Vocês podem me ajudar? Desde já, agradeço muito!!!

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se é o que entendi, bastaria usar o `array_merge`, algo como:

```
public static function setData($type, $data){

    r = array($type=>$data);

    if (!empty($_SESSION[Data::DATA])) {
        r = array_merge($_SESSION[Data::DATA], r);
    }

    $_SESSION[Data::DATA] = r;
}
```

Dessa forma se existir algum valor ele irá combinar o valor com o novo. Talvez possa reduzir o código para:

```
public static function setData($type, $data){
    $_SESSION[Data::DATA] = array_merge((array)$_SESSION[Data::DATA], array($type=>$data));
}
```

Isso faz o mesmo que o primeiro caso, mas mais *gambiarrento*, já que ele converte o valor da sessão para um array (mesmo um `null`), para não *bugar* o `array_merge`, mas...

Comment: Depois de quebrar a cabeça até quase comer um pedaço de parede, a gente não percebe o quanto uma solução pode ser simples. É exatamente isso aí que eu deveria te feito. Me ajudou imensamente! Muito obrigado mesmo!!!